# Wordpress shortcode for tag list

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tags, shortcode

I need to insert tags (of the post) inside post in the exact place. (default: they go after)
As I understand the only way is to use shortcode and write its description in functions. I think its an easy one including "print $tags_list", but I haven't managed to write the whole piece of code needed. 
Can you help me? Or advise another way to solve my problem?
PS: Maybe another way is to insert tag code inside post, but wordpress editor doesn't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a shortcode unless the position changes per post.

To render tags in your template (you could just move the code):

```
 <?php the_tags(); ?>
```

If you wanted to make a shortcode:

```
function sc_taglist(){

    return get_the_tag_list();
}
add_shortcode('tags', 'sc_taglist');
```

And use [tags]

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
In your code tag list is printed in a single word. How to make it divided by commas? (like "wordpress, joomla, ios")

Comment: Format is like this: `get_the_tag_list( $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '', $id = 0 )` so you could do `get_the_tag_list('',', ','')`