# How to get all tags from Wordpress page/post as a list in shortcode?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

At the end of each page and every post, I would like to output the tags as a list in a shortcode.

Unfortunately, I do not know much about PHP, but someone who can understand will definitely be able to correct my mistake using the code below.

Thank you in advance!

```
<?php // functions.php | get tags
function addTag( $classes = '' ) {

    if( is_page() ) {
        $tags = get_the_tags(); // tags
        if(!empty($tags))
        {
            foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
                $tagOutput[] = '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $tags;

}
add_shortcode('tags', 'addTag');
```

Comment: Does this post do what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202455/wordpress-shortcode-for-tag-list

Comment: i tried it, it returned empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method needs to return a string to be able to print any markup.

"Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode." https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

```
function getTagList($classes = '') {
    global $post;
    $tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
    $tagOutput = [];

    if (!empty($tags)) {
        array_push($tagOutput, '<ul class="tag-list '.$classes.'">');
        foreach($tags as $tag) {
            array_push($tagOutput, '<li>'.$tag->name.'</li>');
        }
        array_push($tagOutput, '</ul>');
    }

    return implode('', $tagOutput);
}

add_shortcode('tagsList', 'getTagList');
```

Edit: Removed check for `is_page` since `get_the_tags` will simply return empty if there aren't any

Comment: thank you for you answer! i understand now, thats why he returned "Array" before. I used your code as shortcode [tagsList] and the output is empty. Cant figure it out :/

Comment: I think it has to do with the is_page check like @janh mentioned!

Comment: Is it easier to add this only to posts?

Comment: @adifatz I updated my answer to remove the page check. get_the_tags will handle that for you

Comment: @adifatz, sorry, another edit since get_the_tags requires the post id

Comment: Thanks for your update! Your code should work (with post ID) but it stills returns empty and i cant see why.

Comment: get_the_tags() will default to the current post in the loop (which it should be, as shortcodes are parsed on `the_content` filter). However, if necessary, make sure to add `global $post;` before using it in a function.

Comment: That worked! "global $post;" was missing... Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that pages don't have tags unless you've changed something.

That said, this should work. It also adds the `<ul>` around the tags, but you can change that, and I'm sure you see where. I've used `is_singular`, but you'll probably get away without that condition at all, unless you do add `[tags]` in a custom post type and don't want the output there.
I assume you want to add more modification, otherwise webdevdani's suggestion regarding using [the_tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) is probably simpler.

```
// get tags 
function addTag( $classes = '' ) {
    if( is_singular("post") || is_singular("page") ) {
        $tags = get_the_tags();
        if(is_array($tags) && !empty($tags)) {
            $tagOutput = array("<ul>");
            foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
                $tagOutput[] = '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
            }
            $tagOutput[] = "</ul>";
            return implode("", $tagOutput);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
add_shortcode('tags', 'addTag');
```